# uncalled rule causes unhelpful error message

Tags: antlr4

With the following grammar

```
grammar Gram;

exprEof
    : expr EOF
    ;

expr
    : Uident
    | expr '(' Uident ')'
    ;

Uident
    : [A-Z][a-z]*
    ;

WS
    : [ \n\t]+ -> skip
    ;
```

if I try to parse the input `Foo(A B)` from `exprEof` I get the expected error

```
line 1:6 extraneous input 'B' expecting ')'
```

But if I add an additional rule

```
expr2
    : expr '(' Uident ')'
    ;
```

then the error is

```
line 1:3 mismatched input '(' expecting <EOF>
```

This is surprising because `expr2` is not actually called from `exprEof`. In my full grammar it leads to very unhelpful error messages, where a syntax error deep in an expression is reported as `mismatched input '( expecting <EOF>` near the beginning of the expression.

I'm using ANTLR 4.5.3.

Comment: You may want to file an [issue](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues) for this